# Comparison operator overloading for a struct, symmetrically comparing my struct with an int type?

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload these operators:
`<`, `<=`, `==`, `>=`, `>`, and maybe later `!=`,
in a struct.

It seems that comparing an object of the struct with another *object of the same struct* is easy, because when overloading the operator for that scenario, the definition is automatically symmetric.

But what if I want to compare my struct `FOOD` to an `int`?
This is also easy as long as `FOOD` comes first, *however*, what about the scenario when the int comes first?  How do I define that without g++ giving me so many "must contain exactly one argument" errors?

I realize that

```
bool operator> (const int &, const FOOD &) const;
```

has problems due to the 'more than one argument' thing. I get that.

On all the forums I've search across the interwebs, everyone's solution seems to be using `friend`, but their difficulties are always in the context of classes, not structs. How is this done for s struct?

```
struct FOOD {
    int foodID;
    double price;
    bool operator> (const FOOD  &) const;       //FOOD >  FOOD
    bool operator>=(const FOOD  &) const;       //FOOD >= FOOD
    bool operator==(const FOOD  &) const;       //FOOD == FOOD
    bool operator<=(const FOOD  &) const;       //FOOD <= FOOD
    bool operator< (const FOOD  &) const;       //FOOD <  FOOD
    bool operator> (const int   &) const;       //FOOD >  int 
    bool operator>=(const int   &) const;       //FOOD >= int
    bool operator==(const int   &) const;       //FOOD == int
    bool operator<=(const int   &) const;       //FOOD <= int
    bool operator< (const int   &) const;       //FOOD <  int
    bool operator> (const int &, const FOOD &) const;   // int >  FOOD
    bool operator>=(const int &, const FOOD &) const;   // int >= FOOD
    bool operator==(const int &, const FOOD &) const;   // int == FOOD
    bool operator<=(const int &, const FOOD &) const;   // int <= FOOD
    bool operator< (const int &, const FOOD &) const;   // int <  FOOD
};

bool FOOD::operator> (const FOOD  &f) const {return foodID >  f.foodID;}//FOOD >  FOOD
bool FOOD::operator>=(const FOOD  &f) const {return foodID >= f.foodID;}//FOOD >= FOOD
bool FOOD::operator==(const FOOD  &f) const {return foodID == f.foodID;}//FOOD == FOOD
bool FOOD::operator<=(const FOOD  &f) const {return foodID <= f.foodID;}//FOOD <= FOOD
bool FOOD::operator< (const FOOD  &f) const {return foodID <  f.foodID;}//FOOD <  FOOD
bool FOOD::operator> (const int   &i) const {return foodID >  i;}   //FOOD >  int 
bool FOOD::operator>=(const int   &i) const {return foodID >= i;}   //FOOD >= int
bool FOOD::operator==(const int   &i) const {return foodID == i;}   //FOOD == int
bool FOOD::operator<=(const int   &i) const {return foodID <= i;}   //FOOD <= int
bool FOOD::operator< (const int   &i) const {return foodID <  i;}   //FOOD <  int
bool FOOD::operator> (const int &i, const FOOD &f) const {return i >  f.foodID;}// int >  FOOD
bool FOOD::operator>=(const int &i, const FOOD &f) const {return i >= f.foodID;}// int >= FOOD
bool FOOD::operator==(const int &i, const FOOD &f) const {return i == f.foodID;}// int == FOOD
bool FOOD::operator<=(const int &i, const FOOD &f) const {return i <= f.foodID;}// int <= FOOD
bool FOOD::operator< (const int &i, const FOOD &f) const {return i <  f.foodID;}// int <  FOOD
```

`g++` gives me these errors:

```
structsTransAndFood.cc:64:45: error: ‘bool FOOD::operator>(const int&, const FOOD&) const’ must take exactly one argument
```

Comment: There's no difference between a struct and a class other than the default protection of the members. And you can define all of the operators in terms of `operator<` if you want.

Comment: P.S. Since all the members of a struct are public, there's no need to use `friend` for anything.

Comment: Since an `int foodID` seems to uniquely identify a `FOOD`, you could eliminate all these comparisons by providing a conversion `operator int() const;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define it outside of the `FOOD` struct:

```
bool operator> (const int &i, const FOOD &f) {return i >  f.foodID;}
```

Don't forget to remove this wrong declaration from the `FOOD` struct:

```
bool operator> (const int &, const FOOD &) const; // <--- remove it
```

and the corresponding definition:

```
bool FOOD::operator> (const int &i, const FOOD &f) const {return i >  f.foodID;} // <--- remove it
```

Repeat the same for other operators.

### Solution

You claim that you understand *"more than one argument thing"*. However, it turns out that you don't. I don't get why you have troubles understanding what compiler and 2 people here tell you, but here is how the solution would look like:

```
struct FOOD {
    int foodID;
    double price;

    bool operator> (const FOOD  &) const;
    bool operator>=(const FOOD  &) const;
    bool operator==(const FOOD  &) const;
    bool operator<=(const FOOD  &) const;
    bool operator< (const FOOD  &) const;

    bool operator> (const int   &) const;
    bool operator>=(const int   &) const;
    bool operator==(const int   &) const;
    bool operator<=(const int   &) const;
    bool operator< (const int   &) const;
};

bool FOOD::operator> (const FOOD  &f) const {return foodID >  f.foodID;}
bool FOOD::operator>=(const FOOD  &f) const {return foodID >= f.foodID;}
bool FOOD::operator==(const FOOD  &f) const {return foodID == f.foodID;}
bool FOOD::operator<=(const FOOD  &f) const {return foodID <= f.foodID;}
bool FOOD::operator< (const FOOD  &f) const {return foodID <  f.foodID;}

bool FOOD::operator> (const int   &i) const {return foodID >  i;}
bool FOOD::operator>=(const int   &i) const {return foodID >= i;}
bool FOOD::operator==(const int   &i) const {return foodID == i;}
bool FOOD::operator<=(const int   &i) const {return foodID <= i;}
bool FOOD::operator< (const int   &i) const {return foodID <  i;}

bool operator> (const int &i, const FOOD &f) {return i >  f.foodID;}
bool operator>=(const int &i, const FOOD &f) {return i >= f.foodID;}
bool operator==(const int &i, const FOOD &f) {return i == f.foodID;}
bool operator<=(const int &i, const FOOD &f) {return i <= f.foodID;}
bool operator< (const int &i, const FOOD &f) {return i <  f.foodID;}
```

Comment: `error: ‘bool FOOD::operator>(const int&, const FOOD&) const’ must take exactly one argument`. Did you understand the error message? Operators declared inside classes/structs must take only one explicit parameter. In your case it takes 2, hence the error you get. To solve this problem, just follow my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This type of operator

```
bool operator> (const int &, const FOOD &) const;
```

cannot be a member. A member function takes one extra, implicit parameter of type `FOOD*` (possibly cv qualified), so the example above actually takes three arguments. You need to make it a non-member.

I think the easiest approach would be to give your class an explicit `int` conversion operator

```
explicit operator int() const { return foodID; }
```

Also note that all the comparison operators can be expressed in terms of a single one, for instance `bool operator<` (this technique is used for example in std library associative containers)

Comment: Will simply adding the line
    explicit operator int() const { return foodID; }
into the struct declaration work if I remove all the operator overloads?